# An interesting class

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, knowledge

"Alright, class, I'm seeing so many new faces today. Let's go around and introduce a fun fact about yourself."

A: *"Hey everyone, I'm A. People tell me I'm pretty, but I wish I can buy something with that."*

B: "Hi, I'm B. A fun fact? Let's see...D is my cousin!"

C: "Hi, I'm C. I go by my last name though, S."

D: "*Bonjour. I'm D. B is lying though. He said I'm his cousin just because we have the same last name. We are not even related!*" Everyone laughs so hard that the teacher have to calm the class down before they continued.

E: "*Hi, I'm E. A fun fact about me...uh...My parents own a video store, or at least that's what I think.*"

F: *"Hi! I'm F. People told me I'm messy but I like it. It's not going to be long though because I'm trying to tidy up!"*

G: *"Hey, I'm G. Before anyone ask, I'm 6'5". No I've never played basketball. Love to meet you all since I'm kinda chill with everyone."*

H: "*Hi, I'm H. A fun fact about me? Let's see...I've never seen the ocean*."

I: "*You too, H? Oh, sorry to interrupt. I'm I. I Junior actually because I'm named after my dad.*"

J: "Hi, I'm J. I really like my name because it reminds me of where I'm from."

---

Just as the teacher about to begin the class, a new student ran in.

K: "Sorry, I'm late. The road to school is so long and windy"

Teacher: "That's alright, K. Here, J and G, you two have a sit in between, let K sit there for now.

Class begins. However, two students were missing from that class. Can you tell me which students are missing and where would they sit if they were present in class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the students are:

> Countries in South America, with the order being the countries going clockwise, starting from the top left.

A

> Looks like it should be either Venezuela or Colombia, but I'm not sure which.

B

> Guyana, the "non-French" version of D

C

> Suriname, since it sounds like "surname".

D

> French Guiana

E

> Uruguay, because of its capital city, Montevideo.

F

> Argentina, because "messy" could correspond to Messi, and Messi is most likely retiring soon.

G

> Chile, relating the height to the length of the country, and since "chill" sounds like Chile.

H

> Paraguay, see answer for I as well

I

> Bolivia, since the country is named after Simon Bolivar. That means the other landlocked country is H.

J

> Ecuador, since its name indicates its position on the equator.

K

> Peru, since Peru is famous for having the long Inca Trail.

That means the missing students would be:

> One of Venezuela/Colombia, and Brazil.

Comment: Some of the answers are correct. But try to fill out the rest :) Remember the seating chart too.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a stretch, but here's a partial.

The children are all

> Provinces or Territories of Canada

A:

> Ontario is from an Iroquois word meaning "beautiful lake."

B:

> New Brunswick, where about one-third of the population speak French, therefore: Wannabe cousin of Quebec?

C:

> Nova **S**cotia

D:

> Quebec, the almost cousin of B, both big speakers of French???

E:

> (see note at bottom)

F:

> Yukon, home of the [Messy Church?](https://www.messychurch.org.uk/church/messy-church-yukon-style?zoom=12&lat=60.71918&lon=-135.05363&layers=TTB) (desperate stretch here)

G:

> Nunavut, the Large, chilly territory to the north.

H:

> Saskatchewan, landlocked, just as "I" is.

I:

> Alberta was named after Princess Louise Caroline Alberta, daughter of Queen Victoria and Prince **Albert.**

J:

> British Columbia, comes from Britain?

K:

> Northwest Territory, between Nunavut and British Columbia and home to Windy Bay? :)

Unaccounted for:

> (Prince Edward Island)
>   (Newfoundland and Labrador)
>   (Manitoba)
> Perhaps Manitoba is somehow related to a video store and is child "E," and the others are seated geographically on the east side of the classroom.
> Anyone have any help to give?